# Centering A Caption in CSS

Tags: css, centering

**Background:** I am currently trying to modify my Royal Slider plugin on Wordpress

**Goal:** I wish to make the caption width to 100% (as wide as the picture).

**Issue:** I am struggling with the CSS coding and have been tinkering for awhile with no results.

EDIT:**Current (wrong) Coding:**

Still having issues with it.

```
<div class="rsContent">
  {{image_tag}}
<div class="rsCaption"> 
    <h3>{{title}}</h3> 
    <p>{{description}}</p>
<div class="outerDiv" style="width: 100%"></div>
<div class="sliderDiv style="width: 100%"></div>
<div class="captionDiv" style="width: 100%"></div>
  {{thumbnail}}
  {{html}}
  {{animated_blocks}}
  {{#link_url}}
  <a class="rsLink" href="{{link_url}}">{{title}}</a>
  {{/link_url}}
</div>
```

**Link to the page:** http://www.mountainobsession.com/peaks-o-the-week-mount-temple/

Thanks in advance. I am really struggling with this.

Comment: Inspect the element with `Firebug` or equivalent debugger, and see what styles are being applied to the caption element.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the link to your actual page it will be easier to see what's going on there. Or you can use chrome inspect tool if you want to do that yourself.

Edit: After your link Visit:

I inspected your page and found that class rsGCaption is inheriting your top div css styles. I found that by setting your position attribute from absolute to relative. the only way to fix this is create a outer div

```
<div class="outerDiv"> "Give this width as you like" 
  <div class="sliderDiv> "make width to 100%"
  </div>
  <div class="captionDiv"> "make width to 100%"
  </div>
 "put any number of divs below as you like and don't forget to close them properly"
</div>
```

I have tried this and works for me. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Here is the link: [link](http://www.mountainobsession.com/peaks-o-the-week-mount-temple/)

Comment: hey don't forget to close the sliderDiv, the sliderDiv and captionDiv are two boxes basically